# Import GeoJson into PostgreSQL with psql

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Is there a way to import a `GeoJson` through the commandline into a `table`? Like `shp2pgsql`

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224382/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-postgresql ?

Comment: Ogr2ogr is the best way

Comment: I guess that you have some special reason to avoid using GDAL, is that true?